# Android navigation bar selection does not persist on rotation

Tags: bug, android-app

The selected navigation object does not stay selected when rotating the device, selecting anything other then Quesrions, then rotating the device - I see the selected screen, with the default 'Questions' selection on the nav bar.

[image]